# How to install Package MVTNORM

Tags: r

I am trying to install package mvtnorm, but it says that package ‘mvtnorm’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)....

I believe this is happening cause of R version..... but When I am trying to upgrade R...it is not allowing me to do so. 
I tried to install package "installr" for upgrading R, but it showed the same error - "installr’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4).

There is update tab under "HELP" on the console panel of the studio...it is not responding....

I am using Linux machine for the first time...so i am really confused on how to go about.

I hope to get this thing solved with some help from an expert who can guide me on how to proceed.

Comment: Package `mvtnorm` requires [R (≥ 3.5.0)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html). You need to search a bit more on how to upgrade R on a linux box. It will depend on the distro.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Comment: Check one of the answers on there. It has info on updating R on Linux/Unix(well specifically Ubuntu).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik- Yes...mvtnorm is for >3.5.0. but the issue is the RStudio is not getting upgraded. It is currently showing 3.4.4. No matter what I tried...it is still showing 3.4.4. The inbuilt tab for upgradation of R is also not working...I tried to uninstall and reinstall RStudio.....still the result remained same....I feel that I am doing something principally wrong.....

Comment: @NelsonGon: Good link...but didnt work for me.... :(